# call to undefined function when using laravel belong to relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

To simplify things, let's say that I have 3 tables:

> types: id , name
>   units: id , name , order , visits
>   unit_types: id, typeid , unitid

types model:

```
public function unitTypes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Unit_type' , 'typeid');
}
```

unit model:

```
public function unitTypes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Unit_type' , 'unitid');
}
```

unit_types model :

```
public function unit()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Unit');
}
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Type');
}
```

What I want to achieve is when I get the specific type id, I want to get the units associated with this type and order them.  I tried this but no luck:

```
$units=Unit_type::where('typeid' , '=' ,$id)->unit()->orderBy('visit')->take(10)->get();
```

But in return I get this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::unit()

The Laravel documentation is not clear enough in this kind of situation. So I want to know how to make this kind of queries in Eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To answer your question

The following call is actually returning a collection even if there is only one record matching that id:

```
Unit_type::where('typeid' , '=' ,$id);
```

So what you want to do is just get the first one and call `unit()` on that:

```
$units=Unit_type::where('typeid' , '=' ,$id)->first()->unit()->orderBy('visit')->take(10)->get();
```

---

### Another solution

To get all the units that has a specific type id consider setting up a scope on the unit model:

```
public function scopeOfTypeId($query, $type_id)
{
    return $query->whereHas('unitTypes', function ($where_has_query) use ($type_id) {
        $where_has_query->where('typeid', $type_id);
    });
}
```

Then you could make a call like this to get all the units:

```
$units = Unit::ofTypeId($type_id)->get();
```

> Note: I am guessing the name of your models and columns, so you might need to change some of it.

Comment: and also it returns empty result set

Comment: I've added another solution to my answer

Comment: What do you mean? `get()` is returning a collection of all matching records.

Comment: i was trying the first sulution, and the second one worked like a charm. thanks in advance.